# Can I combine a style that works with different browsers into one CSS?

Tags: css

My skin has the following CSS:

```
dl.definition dd:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* IE class */
dl.definition dd.last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Is it possible to combine these into one even though the second is just for IE ?

Thanks everyone for the answers but I am not sure anyone really said if I could just do this:

```
dl.definition dd:last-child, 
dl.definition dd.last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest trying out a library like [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/), which will allow IE to support CSS such as `:last-child`, so you don't have to write all that browser-specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hoped-for solution won't work:

```
dl.definition dd:last-child, 
dl.definition dd.last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The reason this won't work is because as far as old versions of IE are concerned, `dd:last-child` is an invalid selector, and thus it will throw away the whole block. It doesn't matter that it also contains a valid selector; the whole thing is thrown away because of the invalid one.

A few options on how to improve things, and save yourself the hassle of duplicated code all over the place...

1. Upgrde IE. There are javascript libraries available such as [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) or [ie7.js/ie8.js/ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) which patch IE to make it support more CSS selectors. `:last-child` is included in pretty much all these libraries.
2. Downgrade your CSS. You're already writing the `.last-child` class into your code to support old IE versions, so just use that for everything and forget about using the `:last-child` selector. Then you only need one selector for all browsers.
3. Graceful degradation. Drop the IE-specific code, and just allow Old IE users to see a slightly broken page. As long as it doesn't affect usability, it may not be a big deal. You may not have that many old IE users (and the numbers will continue to fall), and those people who are still using old IE are used to seeing sites that are slightly broken (or worse) these days.
4. Re-arrange your layout to use `:first-child` instead of `:last-child`. `:first-child` has much better support (it goes back to IE7, though there are bugs with it in old IEs).
5. Use a CSS compiler like [SASS or Less](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/), so you can write your CSS in a more logical and structured form, before converting it to real CSS code when you deploy it to the site.

Hopefully one of those solutions will work for you. My suggestion would be the Selectivizr library, but any of the above should provide a workable solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the  **HTML** add

```
<!--[if IE]>    
<style>
    dl.definition dd.last-child {
       margin-bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: +1 you gave a right suggestion but for only internet explorer! :/

Comment: That's what the OP wants ("the second is just for IE").

Comment: well, @Juhana i know you downvoted my POST but you can see the question title : `Can I combine a style that works with different browsers into one CSS?`

Comment: Yes, and the "different browser" is IE. I did not downvote, please don't make accusations based on guesses.

Comment: @Enve - Thanks. I updated the question. Is it possible to do what I suggest at the end of the question. Will that work also?

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to your question but a workaround for IE6 & IE7 can be found [here](http://www.edgeofmyseat.com/blog/all/developing-css-for-ie6-and-7)  which tells that you can use properties in single css file.

[This](http://24ways.org/2005/avoiding-css-hacks-for-internet-explorer/) gives again a more sophisticated solution.

And again you can use multiple properties in single css file and browsers will ignore it if it does not understand it. Cheers to growing smartness of browsers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for IE. You can specify verion of IE, for that you want to select CSS